# How can i make Queries between all collections in firebase in flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i want to do search by a field that in most documents in my collectios  how to do that

[image]

Comment: Please refer  to the https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask questions such that we can help you to the best of our capabilities.

Comment: You could iterate through each collection and retrieve the documents within that collection that match your query. For each document, you retrieve the information you need and then iterate onto the next collection